# Asp net C# Webpage RDLC Report not Showing Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, html, rdlc

I am new to C# and Asp.net and I am trying to use Rdlc Report, but i am not able to print data on Report

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" >
            <LocalReport ReportPath="Report.rdlc">

            </LocalReport>

        </rsweb:ReportViewer>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

         <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>




 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string before = Session["before"].ToString();
        string after = Session["after"].ToString();

        Label1.Text = before.ToString();
        Label2.Text = after.ToString();

        string src = "Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=mydbtry; Integrated Security=true;";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(src);
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            DateTime b = Convert.ToDateTime(before);
            DateTime a = Convert.ToDateTime(after);
            string query = "Select * from firstTable where id = 155";
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            DataSet ds;
            using (con)
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);

                }
            }

            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report.rdlc");
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0]);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();                
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }


    }
```

> > The problem i am facing right now is, my table is empty and data not populated.
> >     I am using sql server 2012 and i already checked the connection which is working fine.
> >
> > After Execution

[image]

> > DataSet

[image]

> > Report.RDLC

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to populate your report through ***ObjectDataSource*** control. It works automatically, not need to put any code

Comment: I already solved the problem myself; my DataSet did not retieved correct table... Thanks anyway.